# Injecting a Resource into a Stateless Local EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jboss5.x

I have an @Local interface with an @Stateless implementation.

On the implementation is an @Resource(mappedName="java:/XXMail") javax.mail.Session.

It remains null though and isn't injected, but a JNDI lookup via an InitialContext works fine.

Any ideas what I can check or how I can debug this? Several of us have poured over this for a while without any luck. Apologies, I can't post code itself as it's on a closed network.

Comment: But you can create sample app which is reproducing the problem so there we could try it and reproduce it too.

Comment: I don't see that adding any value.

Comment: I can see that you've tagged this as jboss-5.x, but which specific version is this, and can you post the configuration of your mail session?

Comment: How did you obtain an instance of the EJB?  Perhaps some sample code of the EJB and its client would clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Although this certain issue might not be relevant any longer, the root problem and its solution may be valuable for others. In most cases the problem is caused by instantiating a new object of the implementating bean instead of using the proxy interface, like:

```
ObjectBean obj = new ObjectBean();
```

This will not trigger CDI and therfore all annotated resources will be ***null***. Using the interface instead by looking up via JNDI or annotated resource will resolve the issue:

```
ObjectBeanInterface obj = new InitialContext().lookup("java:module/ObjectBean!org.mycompany.ObjectBeanInterface");
```